# Add data from many-to-many to selection data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
"tags"
id serial
name text
```

```
"questions"
id serial
content jsonb
```

```
"questions_tags" (many-to-many)
question_id integer
tag_id integer
```

I can select all data from questions:

```
SELECT * FROM questions;
```

I can select tags of specific question:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tags t
JOIN questions_tags qt ON t.id = qt.tag_id
JOIN questions q ON qt.question_id = q.id
WHERE q.id = 157;
```

I need to select all questions and add to this selection tags for every question.
I'm using nodejs and node-postgres and I need to get something like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    content: { someProp: 'someValue' },
    tags: [
      { id: 58, name: 'sometag58' },
      { id: 216, name: 'sometag216' }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

How can I do this without ORM, only with the help of vanilla SQL?

Comment: it is very unclear as you didn't add any data to your question content is json but in your wanted result it is varchar, ttat is very confusing

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. In addition, JSON can be just a string, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let PostgreSQL handle it for me:

```
with tagjson as (
  select q.id, q.content, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(tags)) as tags
    from questions q
         left join questions_tags qt on qt.question_id = q.id
         left join tags on tags.id = qt.tag_id
   group by q.id, q.content
)
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(tagjson))) as result
  from tagjson;
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 58,
                "name": "sometag58"
            },
            {
                "id": 216,
                "name": "sometag216"
            }
        ],
        "content": "some question 1 content"
    }
]
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=208379ddf037066d2ab8db5a18966ed5)*

EDIT TO ADD:

Based on a conversation in the comments, the final query should be modified to:

```
select * from tagjson;
```

Or the CTE could be promoted to be a stand-alone query.

This allowed the conventional node syntax while preserving the aggregated `tags` array under the `tags` key:

```
const questions: Question[] = result.rows;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but now result from node-postgres is in a very unusual form.
Previosly my code in questionsService.ts was :
`const questions: Question[] = result.rows;`
now it:
`const questions: Question[] = JSON.parse(result.rows[0].result);`
`result` - is a promise result of  node-progres `query()` function.

Comment: @DmitriyZhuravlev I don't use JS, but try getting rid of the `jsonb_pretty()`.  If that doesn't work, then cast the result to text (e.g. `jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(tagjson))::text`).

Comment: @DmitriyZhuravlev  I just now saw the edit to your comment.  I used the `jsonb` functions to nest the tags.  What happens if you just `select * from tagjson` ?  Will node figure out that the tags are a child array and construct your objects correctly?

Comment: Omg, thank you!
This is exactly what I need for JS/TS node-postgres!
`with tagjson as (...SQL...) select * from tagjson;` works.